# Fetching data from a MySQL Database with AngularJS factory

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and willing to know it.

I want to use a factory service to get data from a MySQL Database and pass this data to my controller.

connect.php

```
      $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','db1975','testang', '3306');

     if(!$conn){
        die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
     }

   $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
   $result = $conn->query($query);
   $data = array();

  if( $result->num_rows>0){
       while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
          $data[] = $row;
      }
   }

   echo json_encode($data);
```

Here's my service,

```
    app.factory ('repertoire', ['$http', function($http){

        $http.get('controllers/data/connect.php').then(function ImSuccessful(data) {
        return data;
    });
   }]);
```

and finally my controller :

```
   app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'repertoire',function($scope){

        $scope.liste = data.data;
        $scope.titre = "Liste";



     }]);
```

It says tjhat repertoire doesn't return any value but i can't figure why

Comment: Does 'Select * From Users' actually return  anything? Is the table empty?

Comment: Yes it returns a JSON :[{"id":"1","nom":"Paul Simon","age":"78","photo":"images\/thumbnail.jpg"},{"id":"2","nom":"Charles Aznavour","age":"92","photo":"images\/thumbnail.jpg"},{"id":"3","nom":"Paul Simon","age":"78","photo":"images\/thumbnail.jpg"},{"id":"4","nom":"Charles Aznavour","age":"92","photo":"images\/thumbnail.jpg"},{"id":"5","nom":"Jarre","age":"68","photo":"images\/thumbnail.jpg"}]

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is that you try it out on plnkr.co and see if that helps. you can replace your http call with a function that just returns the result set you've posted.